# Freelancing in highschool?

Tags: working-from-home, usa, web-development

I am currently a high school student and I'm looking to start working. I am not able to drive myself around yet so I have my eyes on freelancing right now.

So far I have these certifications:

- Microsoft 2013; Word (and Expert), PowerPoint, Excel, SharePoint, Outlook, and OneNote
- Adobe Flash CS6
- Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 and CC 2015 (with about 2 years experience)
- MTA Networking Fundamentals
- CompTIA Net+

I was looking towards redesigning websites since I read that Google lowers the SEO ratings for non-responsive websites. I've also been working in 3ds Max, though I still consider myself a beginner. Would someone even hire a student? And what other types of freelancing jobs would I be able to take?

Comment: I voted to close this quest because it's just too broad. Realize that if you are under 18 years old (in the US) you are not legally an adult, and as such can not be bound by any contract... few will enter into business deals with minors due to this. If you flake out with their money... they'd have a difficult time recovering it.

Comment: Could a parent or guardian be tied to the contract in place of the minor?

Comment: In most cases yes. But I'm not a lawyer and haven't really had a whole lot of similar dealings. I honestly avoid business with minors if the fees are more than a dinner out.

Comment: I'd say start doing some pro bono work with charities and foundations to build your experience and resume. By the time you reach 18 you are ready to go.

Comment: While I agree the question is broad, the comments do actually contain answer-like relevant information.

Comment: I don't claim to be a developer but I think Flash is "long ago" for websites. Thankfully I have good backend coders now but when I look for people I need graphics (photoshop), HTML5, CSS, Angular, JS things like that. None of the people I have used recently do any Dreamweaver or Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never stop learning.

Build something just for the hell of it. (Start with a blog or a portfolio) At least in my experience freelancing, not many people will care what specific software you know how to use. They will care, however, about your results.

So even if you can't get someone to pay you yet, make stuff anyway. I'd be a whole lot more likely to work with a High School student if they had a profile full of practice projects for made up companies, than a High School student with just a resume full of certifications.